# How would I add a scrollview indicator with words?

Tags: ios, swift

I can change the color of a scrollview indicator, but I am lost on how to have words as the scroll view indicator. For example say the first page is blankets, and the second is pillow, and they are in a scroll view. In the toolbar it will say blankets and pillows, and a line will appear under it indicating the user is on that page. Below is the only thing I have done, I am completely lost on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

```
tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface yourViewcontroller ()
{
 NSArray * IndexTitles;
}

  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  IndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

 }

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return IndexTitles;
}
```